# Nested Promises - Map function inside a map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

basically I have a big array with object values like this:

```
[{
  - Champion Name
  - [Another Array with Skins information]
}]
```

so what I want to do is run a map function inside the second array to get a value for everyone of these skins so what I did was.

```
const got = require('got');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const getSkinData = async champSkins => {
  const data = JSON.parse(champSkins);

  const handleMap = skin => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const name = skin.split(' ').join('_');

        const { body } = await got(`https://lol.gamepedia.com/${name}`);

        const $ = cheerio.load(body);

        const skinLink = $('.InfoboxSkin img').attr('src') || '';

        const skinInfo = {
          skinName: skin,
          skinLink
        };

        resolve(skinInfo);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    });
  };

  Promise.all(
    data.map(async ({ skins }) => {
      return Promise.all(
        skins.map(skin => {
          return handleMap(skin);
        })
      );
    })
  ).then(data => console.log(data));
};

module.exports = getSkinData;
```

but it didn't actually work, I couldn't access the data and the console.log inside the promise at the end didn't even run.

any idea how to do it or is there a better way to do it?

EDIT #1

basically 'skins' for every champ is an array of strings like:

```
[ 'Aatrox',          
  'Justicar Aatrox', 
  'Mecha Aatrox',    
  'Sea Hunter Aatrox'
  'Blood Moon Aatrox'
  'Blood Moon Aatrox 
  'Victorious Aatrox' ]

[ 'Ahri',            
  'Dynasty Ahri',    
  'Midnight Ahri',   
  'Foxfire Ahri',    
  'Popstar Ahri',    
  'Challenger Ahri', 
  'Academy Ahri',    
  'Arcade Ahri',     
  'Star Guardian Ahri
  'K/DA Ahri',       
  'K/DA Ahri Prestige
  'Elderwood Ahri' ]
```

and skin is just every value of the array

and the value that comes back from the scraping is just a link for each skin

[image]

Comment: Does your function `handleMap` work on its own?

Comment: @abondoa it does i console logged the value of skin info and it worked perfectly fine

Comment: Can you add `console.log` inside your map functions to see what the `skins` and `skin` actually look like?

Comment: I edited and added more info in the question:)

Comment: An async function that returns `Promise.all` will result in a double promise.

Comment: @Aplet123 I'm sorry do you mind explaning? im new to the concept of promises in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getSkinData = async champSkins => {
    const data = JSON.parse(champSkins);
    // async that returns promise is a double promise, you only need async
    const handleMap = async skin => {
        try {
            const name = skin.split(" ").join("_");
            const { body } = await got(`https://lol.gamepedia.com/${name}`);
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);
            const skinLink = $(".InfoboxSkin img").attr("src") || "";
            const skinInfo = {
                skinName: skin,
                skinLink
            };
            // changed resolve to return
            return skinInfo;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    };

    return await Promise.all(data.map(({ skins }) => Promise.all(skins.map(skin => handleMap(skin)))));
};
```

Async functions return a promise that resolves with their return value, so returning a promise from an async function is redundant and ends up causing a nested promise. Also, you don't have to use `.then` in async functions because you can just `await` the promise. Read more about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: I'm getting a very werid error saying that const { body } = await got(`ht...<omitted>... } is not iterable, any idea what that means?

Comment: i literally deleted everything in handleMap and still get the same error.

Comment: i still cant figure where the error is coming from, do you mind it if I got the project on github and linked in to you?

Comment: Can we [move this to chat?](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210551/https-stackoverflow-com-q-60920722-5923139)